# What reasons and circumstances should javadoc/phpdoc be chosen over regular comments?

Tags: php, coding-style, comments, javadoc, phpdoc

What reasons and circumstances should javadoc/phpdoc be chosen over regular comments? I know what the syntax difference is but why use one or the other. Is it mainly semantic or are there other reasons why I should use one over the other, and what are they?

I don't really understand the purpose of javadoc/phpdoc comments. What is wrong with the next block of code? ... is the `/**` just a way of making certain comments turn a different colour in the editor ... some editors don't differentiate (vanilla sublime doesn't seem to) ?

```
/*
 * This block is wrapped in /** */ not /* */
 * Some documentation goes here
 * Below is copied from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
```

Another question ... would there be any reason why I should use both `/** */` and `/* */` in the same file?

Final question ... Why are javadoc/phpdoc comments seemingly associated with classes ... but yet I have seen them used as sort of introduction comments to a page which is what I originally understood them to be?

actually yet another ... at the risk of answering my own question I wonder are the javadoc/phpdoc comments really just a way of differentiating between comments that were written automatically by the tool and ones that were written by the developer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole reason people use Javadoc is for **consistency** and **readability** - if you know the syntax it makes it easy to look at someone else's code (or vice-versa), and understand the meaning straight away. Rather than having something like:

```
// This method is used for counting sheep just before bed time
// It's really awesome, and takes the bed-time, and also age,
// And also number of sheep, in reverse order.
```

Which takes time to process; it's far nicer to see:

```
/**
 * Count the number of sheep at bedtime
 *
 * @author Tom Walters 
 *
 * @param sheep   The number of sheep to count
 * @param age     The age of the person going to bed
 * @param bedTime The time of going to bed in 24hr format
 * @return The sheep were counted successfully
 */
```

Immediately you can see how many parameters there are, and what each of them is for. The same goes for the return type. It's also highly useful when working in teams to have the author up there, then you know who to shout at when the sheep go astray.

As for the `/**` - it helps differentiate this style from things like random comments and on-line comments and is a nice convention to help Javadoc stick out when browsing code.

As a rule you you'll be maintaining code more than you write it, so having a well-defined syntax like this is a great idea - it'll lead to you being to allocate more time to thinking about problem-solving, rather than **deciphering large blocks of text** for basic information.

Comment: I'd say another important reason is that you can generate javadoc from the comments. It is sort of obvious but I almost get the impression that the OP didn't know that...

Comment: Excellent point, it's all about making the programmer's life easier!

Comment: Thanks. Nice answer but it doesn't really answer my question. I still don't understand why the above example couldn't have been done using a regular block comment. By the way I understand the difference between javadoc and single comments, just not block comments ( other than the extra * and different colour in some editors )

Comment: Think about it like this: You write `javadoc` for the users of your code - maybe in a public API, but you'd use standard block comments for developers of your code - other people who are directly altering it. The `/**` syntax was simply decided upon for the `javadoc` tool as a delimiter when parsing the comments.

Comment: would it be true to say then that there's no real hard and fast rule about it but that you'd generally use doc type comments for overview type information ( falling somewhere between comments and a readme file ) and regular block comments would be maybe limited to a function or something ... if so then what I find confusing is that javadoc/phpdoc comments often seem to be used for classes ... is this because we would want to actually "Document" the classes rather than comment on them ... sorry am a bit lost on the semantics of it

Comment: No doubt _some_ programmers will debate in-depth on the topic, but in general you're correct. Jdoc is good for expressing moderate complexity in an overview-type fashion of class methods etc., where blocks might be used for particularly complex functionality. Comments should usually be about documenting your code when the meaning isn't a few seconds of thinking.

Comment: Thanks ... have just realised something in your answer ... the `@param` and `@return` ... are these in any way relevant to a file which contains no classes, only functions? Every tutorial I found uses a file containing classes in it's example?

Comment: They apply across the board - class or no class. Classes are just often well documented as they're self-contained collections of code that often requires extensive documentation.

Comment: aah ... the penny drops ... thanks ... I somehow got the idea that `@param` and `@return` could only be used wrt classes. All makes sense now ... also I feel silly because I just read Uby's answer again and he actually mentioned this

Comment: @byronyasgur You do know that the javadoc comments are used to create HTML documentation about the interfaces and classes? It is not just "any code comments". The javadoc tool is the thing generating pages like this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
If you want things to be in your class documentation, it should be javadoc comments.

Comment: @Fredrik ... are you saying then that it should or shouldn't be used for functions ... I am actually confused again

Comment: Javadoc comments are used to document classes, interfaces, enums and everything else that typically ends up in the javadoc. You should use it to document purpose, parameters, return values, exceptions and other relevant things related to the interface you want to document in your javadoc (the HTML based documentation of the code you write). The big difference compared to ordinary comments is that they document the code and what it does. Putting a javadoc comment before a statement doesn't make sense. javadoc will not care, it can just as well be a plain comment.

Comment: @Fredrik not sure what interfaces and enums but can you specifically clear up about whether it should be used for functions. I don't understand why you made your original comment otherwise.

Comment: Functions/methods are part of the public/protected/private interface of a class, interface or enum. If you want the method to be documented by the javadoc tool you should use javadoc comments, otherwise it doesn't matter. Look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase(java.util.Locale) It is ALL created from the data specified in javadoc comments. Had the javadoc comment been replaced with an ordinary comment, you would have seen the first line "public String toUpperCase(Locale locale)" and nothing more.

Comment: @Fredrik No I just want to be clear whether I can/cannot use javadoc/phpdoc with regular functions ... nothing to do with classes

Comment: You can but it doesn't make more sense than to start a comment with /******************* (which is fine of course).

Answer (score 3):

The form `/** */` is usually used for **documentation**. So if you want to document a class, a file, a function, a class method, a class field or a variable you should use that form.

The form `/* */` contains just code comments, just like `//`.

Some IDE will use phpDoc information contained within `/** */` blocks to show you some hint. Also, software like [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) use `/** */` blocks to generate documentation files.

Answer (score 1):

Going over all the comments and discussions above, it sounds like you still have questions about using Javadoc comments on functions alone.  The answer would be **YES**, you can use javadoc comments on functions that do not need to be in a class definition.

Why use javadoc comments over regular comments? The main reason would be to use the Javadoc tool which will create a local API (html) reference document that explains how to use your functions and what return types to expect from those functions (and class methods).  Without the javadoc comments, the Javadoc tool would have nothing to put into the generated API document.  What you put in the javadoc comments is what will be formatted into the html files for your own API.  The javadoc tool sees the /** as special comment and reads that content.  A Java compiler (or PHP interpreter) will see the /** and think it's a /* ignoring everything until the next */, they treat it as any regular comment.

So if you plan on having a easy to read click-able linked reference document, javadoc comments are absolutely necessary, if not, they make no difference.  However, having the Javadoc API as a reference is a huge time saver to look at how your functions work without having to find them in code.

Having the Javadoc API of my files, is great if I need some one else to help on a project.  It's much easier to click a hyperlink in a web browser to see a function's explanation instead of finding the file, opening the file, looking for the function, reading the code and determining what it does.

Let's use this example:

```
public int addSquares( int x, int y ) {
  int value = x*x + y*y;
  return value;
}
```

On it's own you have to read that this function takes two ints, squares both and returns the sum of both squares.  if we were to Javadoc the function with:

```
/**
* Squares two numbers, and returns the sum of those squared numbers.
* @param x first value to square
* @param y second value to square
* @return value of x*x + y*y
*/
```

if you ran your .java file through the Javadoc tool, you'd have an html file that showed:

```
int addSquares( int x, int y )
    Squares two numbers, and returns the sum of those squared numbers.
```

This gives you the return type, parameters, and short description of the function.  Also 'addSquares' would be a hyperlink to the more descriptive section in the same HTML page, which would look similar to:

**addSquares**
*public int addSquares( int x, int y )*
Squares two numbers, and returns the sum of those squared numbers.

*Parameters:*
x first value to square
y second value to square

*Returns:*
value of x*x + y*y

Yes, for this example it very simple to read the code, but when your functions/methods/classes become more complex, it's much faster to use the reference API documented that was created  by the Javadoc comments.  So unless you plan on creating the reference API documentation, javadoc comments are no different than regular comments, other than they give a different color in your editor.